# Get canvas pixel position from mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a 16x16 canvas that is scaled with CSS (`width:90%; height: auto;`) and I'm attempting to convert mouse coordinates on the canvas to one of the 16x16 pixels. I'm taking it from an `onmousemove` event, and while I can get the raw screen coordinates, I need to get where it lies on the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector( 'canvas' );

canvas.addEventListener( 'mousemove', event => {
    
    const bb = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = Math.floor( (event.clientX - bb.left) / bb.width * canvas.width );
    const y = Math.floor( (event.clientY - bb.top) / bb.height * canvas.height );
    
    console.log({ x, y });
  
});
```

```css
html,body { height: 100%; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<canvas width="16" height="16"></canvas>
```

So you simply take the coordinate, take of the offset of the canvas (fullscreen that would be `0`), then divide it by the visual width of the canvas and multiply by the actual width of the canvas. If you `floor` that you get a rounded pixel coordinate.

The above code works for any size canvas, since it keeps in mind the offset it has from the screen (also `client` in mouse coordinate). SO whatever the width of your canvas, this should return the correct pixel.

Comment: Worked perfectly, though I had to subtract 1 from X and Y to get it to be accurate.