# How to capture the mouse position on a canvas modified with devicePixelRatio?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I have a canvas whose image was of poor quality on mobile. What I did was adapt the dimensions to the `window.devicePixelRatio`:

```
        const canvas = canvasRef.current
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

        const image = new Image()
        image.src = backgroundImage
        image.onload = () => {
          onLoadCanvas()

          if (isMobile) {
            const devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1

            canvas.width = window.innerWidth * devicePixelRatio
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight * devicePixelRatio
          }

          context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        }
```

But I had an `eventListener` that captured the mouse positions. Now mouse positions are being captured erroneously.

```
let rectLeft = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left
let rectTop = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top

let x = isMobile ? e.touches[0].pageX - rectLeft : e.layerX
let y = isMobile ? e.touches[0].pageY - rectTop : e.layerY
```

What should I do to capture correctly?

Comment: Just for the record, do you want to get the event position to match the pixels on the page or to match the pixels on the canvas?

Comment: to match the pixels on the canvas

Comment: You could just multiply your x and y values with devicePixelRatio. That way the position should be correct.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72379573/get-canvas-pixel-position-from-mouse-coordinates for reference.

If you want your pixels to match exactly, you could go for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610164/set-viewport-to-match-physical-pixels